# Why were the Kwons candidates if Jacob said he chose the others because they were "all alone in the world"?

Tags: lost

I'm just finishing up Lost.  In one of the last episodes Jacob is sitting around the fire with Jack, Kate, Hugo and Sawyer.  When asked why he chose them to be candidates he said something to the effect that they were each all alone with nobody and lost in the world.  He also tells Kate the reason he crossed her name off was because she was a mother.

But the Kwons were both married (so not all alone) and had a child, so why was one of them still a candidate (until they were drowned)?  Is there any logical reason within the show or given outside of it by the makers?  Is this just a case of "characters don't always tell the absolute truth, especially in Lost"?

Comment: I don't think you'll get a story-internal answer here. It's clear to me (even as a fan of the show) that by this point the makers had abandoned all hope of finishing the story logically, and were just making it up as they went along.

Comment: Man, everyone is so negative about the way they ended it.  I like it.

Comment: @zipquincy The problem is not really about the ending itself, it's the fact that the ending didn't provide the explanations people had been led to believe existed, and would be delivered before the end. So it's more the story itself people are annoyed about.

Comment: @IlariKajaste anybody who expected _all_ the mysteries to be solved... well, it isn't scooby doo, it's lost!

Comment: @zipquincy I think many honestly expected at least most mysteries, or at least the most important ones, to be solved. Only at the end did we find out some people seem to consider it somehow rewarding to just throw together random mysterious elements that sound impressive. We disappointed ones seem to only consider mysterious elements impressive because we expect the mystery to come from clever concealment of the underlying structure. These are two different approaches to mystery, I guess. A mean way to put it would be saying some appreciate just the surface, and others care what's beneath it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Kwons were pretty lost. It is quite possible to be alone, even in the company of other people. The child didn't help that much, either. The family only found their warmth for each other again when on the island.

But really, the whole premise is such a strech, and full of weakly patched or outright gaping holes, that I don't see much reason in trying to inject sense to it. It just won't stick, no matter how elaborate the attempt...